# how cpu calculates system time even after shutting down?

Tags: system, cpu, clock

When we switch off our pc, even after that when we switch it on again then it shows correct system time. How that happens without power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CMOS battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery) will keep the clock running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a battery inside of your motherboard to maintain correct time and some settings.
You can [google images about it](https://www.google.ru/search?q=battery%20motherboard&tbm=isch)